# Accessing an anchor on a relative URL

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting up a template for about 30 pages, which means I can't use absolute URL's, but the structure and parent of each page is going to be the same (it will just contain different information). I couldn't find a way to combine a relative URL with an anchor tag, but I did manage to accomplish this using Javascript. I feel like I've completely overcomplicated it though and even though it works, there must be a better way.
Here's my JS, which is executed at before the closing body tag.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var file = url.split('?')[0];
var pathanddomain = file.split('/');
var path = pathanddomain.splice(1, pathanddomain.length-1);
var pathIndexToGet = 3;
var anchor1 = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec1';
var anchor2 = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec2';
var anchor3 = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec3';
var anchor4 = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec4';
var link1 = document.getElementById('seclink1');
var link2 = document.getElementById('seclink2');
var link3 = document.getElementById('seclink3');
var link4 = document.getElementById('seclink4');
link1.href = anchor1;
link2.href = anchor2;
link3.href = anchor3;
link4.href = anchor4;
```

And the HTML which it refers to:

```
<a id="seclink1">Section 1</a>
<a id="seclink2">Section 2</a>
<a id="seclink3">Section 3</a>
<a id="seclink4">Section 4</a>
```

Is this the most efficient way of accomplishing this task?

Would combining it into one line work as well as being more efficient, rather than using variables so frequently? i.e.

```
document.getElementById('seclink1').href = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec1';
```

Comment: Combining things in single line may not differ much in performance.
To simplify , you may store the section id's in an array and iterate it to create the anchor tags.may be check about implementing  pagination effectively in  fronted that may helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple like:

```
var url = location.pathname;
var anchor = url.split("/").pop();
for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
document.getElementById(`seclink${i}`).href = '../' + anchor + `#sec${i}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, yes it will be more efficient,and combined for loop is more readable.

```
for(var i = 1 ; i <= linksNumber ; i++){
  document.getElementById('seclink'+i).href = '../' + (path[pathIndexToGet]) + '#sec'+i;
}
```